# How use forEach to make decisions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have the following array:

```
var array = [10, 15, 20];
```

and i have also this variable called N:

```
var N = 20;
```

I and make a loop and check all the itens inside, the N must be greater them all numbers so i can call functionA, if is not, i want call other function

```
array.forEach(function (item) {
  if (N > All) {
    callFunctionA();
  } else if (N > onlySomes) {
    callFunctionB();
  }

});
```

But the problem is that if the first number of the array is smaller them the number, the function will be called, and i want check all the numbers.. This is possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear if you only want the function to be called once in the event one or more of the numbers in the array is greater N.

If you want it to be called **EACH TIME** it finds a number in the array greater than N, what you have is fine.

If you only want to determine if the function should be called or not, and **CALL IT ONCE**, replace your function call with a boolean variable that's set to false when N is defined, and set it to true inside the if statement. It won't matter if multiple iterations set it to true.

After the loop, check if the boolean is true, and if so call the funciton.

Example:

> ```
> var array = [10, 15, 20];
> var fireCallback = false;
> var N = 20;
>
> array.forEach(function (item) {
>   if (N > item) {
>     fireCallback = true;
>     //callFunction();
>   } 
>
> });
> if (fireCallback) {
>     callFunction();
> }
> ```

Another approach you could try (if you only want it to fire once) is finding the largest number in the array using Math.max:

```
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, array); // 306
```

Then checking if the largest number is bigger than N

```
if(largest >= N) {
    callFunction();
}
```

Comment: It's also worth nothing that you can't break out of a forEach loop. If your array might be rather large (hundreds of indices), then you'll want to change to using a traditional for loop so you can break out of the loop as soon as the condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `boolean` and set it `false` if a number is larger than `N`. Similarly use a second boolean to check if there is at least one number which is smaller than `N`.

```
var allAreSmaller = true;
var someAreSmaller = false;
array.forEach(function (item) {
  if (N <= item) {
    allAreSmaller = false;
  } 
  if (N > item)
    someAreSmaller = true;
});

if (allAreSmaller)
    callFunctionA();
else if (someAreSmaller)
    callFunctionB()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and Array.some()

```
var flag1 = array.every(function (item) {
    return N > item;
});
var flag2 = array.some(function (item) {
    return N > item;
});

if (flag1) {
    callFunctionA();
} 
if (flag2) {
    callFunctionB();
}
```

Comment: every? I've never heard about it.. this is new?

Comment: @AmandaFerrari it is in ES5 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you are doing in your loop, you could use a `filter` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var areAllSmaller = array.filter(function(_item){ return _item > N}).length <= 0; // true or false
```

Tenta aê!